# Jest: Testing API Methods from Intercom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am having trouble understanding what the testing flow would be for testing functions which use functions loaded from a **JavaScript** library from Intercom.

My method looks like this:

```
 export const generateButton = (handleOnClick) => {
    case "moo":
        return <button onClick={() => Intercom('show')}>Sign Up</button>
    default: 
        return 'moo'
```

The error I get when running this is:

> ReferenceError: Intercom is not defined

Comment: Are you importing `Intercom` on your test file where you are trying to run the function?

Comment: No, intercom is from CDN and I don't want the jest tests to download from it every time it runs

Comment: So your trying to test the function which uses Intercom, but you don't want to test Intercom itself?

Comment: exactly, I want the test to ignore the Intercom portion entirely

Comment: Added an answer that should work for what you're wanting to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out, I needed to add a new file and point jest set up on package.json to it like so (the file added is mockObject)

```
"setupFiles": [
  "./config/jest/setupJest.js",
  "./config/jest/mockObject.js"
],
```

then in the file itself has this in it

```
global.Intercom = () => {
   console.log('Intercom called')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand what you're trying to do then create a dummyFunction to replace Intercom in your tests. Something like this...

```
const Intercom = jest.fn();

describe('button click', () => {
    it('Intercom is called correctly', () => {
        // whatever component contains the button should be mounted
        const wrapper = mount(<YourComponentHere />);

        // you may need to add a class to target the specific button
        wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');

        expect(dummyFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith('show');
        expect(dummyFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: unfortunately the same outcome, ReferenceError: Intercom is not defined. I believe it is because Intercom itself is not exposed to the Jest environment but is called directly

Comment: You may need to import it, even if not calling it.

Comment: If someone is going to downvote then you should at least leave a comment as to why. I was trying to be helpful and downvoting should be left for useless answers...